# Quickjs -- Running code on Promise completion or rejection

Tags: javascript, quickjs

I am using `quickjs` js engine. As a part of my requirments, I wanted to create a Promise and do certain actions when its resolved or rejected. (Basically do set `then` and `catch` functions).
I know promise is created as such:

```c
JSValue resolvingFuncs[2];
JSValue promise = JS_NewPromiseCapability(ctx,resolvingFuncs);
```

The two resolving functions be the `resolve` and `reject`. But how do I set `then` and `catch` functions ?

Comment: `then` and `catch` are methods on the promise object.

Comment: @AbrarHossain yes they are. But they are called automaically when Promise is resolved and rejected. I wanted a way to pass functiosn to `then` and `catch` from the C side. I am implemneting writable stream and as a part of specification oneed to create a promise and do certain task upon its completion or rejection.

Comment: @AbrarHossain yes treating it that way worked!. Thank you.

Comment: @AnuragVohra can you post host you solved this?

Comment: @AbrarHossain Can you possibly provide an answer that details you comment?

Comment: @JSON Use `JS_GetPropertyStr` to get `then` property of a promise. Then call `then` function using `JS_Call` method passing it the custom call back you wanted to be called upon promise completion. See this JS code `promise.then(callbackfunction)`, if you observe this code `then` is a function which needs to be called to set a callback upon promise completion.

Answer (score 1):

Just save resolve and reject in C, and call resolve or reject function using JS_Call function.

Like this:

```
JSValue ret = JS_Call(data->sp_ctx->js_ctx, data->resolve, data->promise, 1, &file_handle_value);
if(JS_IsError(data->sp_ctx->js_ctx, ret) || JS_IsException(ret)) {
    js_std_dump_error(data->sp_ctx->js_ctx);
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on this answer? I'm interested in doing exactly what you're suggesting but there's very little context to go off of.